# Complicated C type and Boolean expression explanation

Tags: c, gdb

Using GDB I have the following data:

```
ptype phases
type = _Bool (*[6])(char *)

ptype phases[0]
type = _Bool (*)(char *)
```

First, what is the type on variable `phases` in English? I am new to GDB and C so I am not sure if this is a type in C or some display convention in GDB. If I do the following:

```
p phases
$9 = {0x400880 <phase0>, 0x4008c0 <phase1>, 0x400920 <phase2>, 0x400a10 <phase3>, 0x400ba0 <phase4>, 0x400c50 <phase5>}
```

the way the data is presented in GDB, is `phases` an array of bool, string pairs?

Second question, I have the following line in logic that I don't understand (simplified for this question):

```
if(!((phases[0])("test"))) {
```

I have no idea how this expression is evaluated. `phases[0]` gives a `_Bool (*)(char *)`. Then we have the `"test"` char pointer with no explicit operation in between that and `phases[0]`. How is this evaluated and what is this called?

Comment: `phases[0] gives a _Bool (*)(char *)` Right, so that's a pointer to a function that takes a `char*` argument and returns a `_Bool`. So you call it with `"test"` as an argument, then check the `_Bool` return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is an array of function pointers, where each function accepts a single `char *` parameter and returns a `_Bool`.

Looking at the given expression:

```
(!((phases[0])("test")))
```

`phases[0]` is a single function pointer in the array.  It is called (`(phases[0])("test")`) with `"test"` as a parameter.  Then the `_Bool` value that is returned is negated with the logical NOT operator `!`.